# Client acknowledgement mode doesn't work in activemq

Tags: spring-boot, queue, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I spent a long time on this problem and I can't figure it out. Maybe I'm not understanding client acknowledgment correctly?

I have a activemq consumer and I configured a **client acknowledgment** for it. When I check the acknowledgement mode in debug, I see that it's correctly set to 2.

I wanted to check that if I **don't call** **message.acknowledge()**, **message will be resent again or it will go back to the broker.**

However, it doesn't happen. Even though I don't acknowledge the message, it still shows as successfully dequeued.

What am I doing wrong?

```
package test.config;

import javax.jms.Session;    
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@Configuration
public class ConnectionFactoryConfig {

    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    public PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
        final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(createActiveMQConnectionFactory());
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(2);
        return pooledConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(pooledConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory());
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
        return factory;
    }


    private ActiveMQConnectionFactory createActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        factory.setUserName(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setRedeliveryPolicy(createRedeliveryPolicy());
        return factory;
    }

    private RedeliveryPolicy createRedeliveryPolicy() {
        final RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(13000);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }
}
```

CONSUMER

```
package poc.consumers;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.activemq.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "queue.test", containerFactory = "myJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Consumer");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will only be requeued if the listener throws an exception (or you shut down the app, or otherwise close the `Session`).

As far as the broker knows, your consumer is still working on it.

See `Session.recover()` - this is the code in the container, called when the listener throws an exception...

```java
            else if (isClientAcknowledge(session)) {
                session.recover();
            }
```

```java
/** Stops message delivery in this session, and restarts message delivery
  * with the oldest unacknowledged message.
  *  
  * <P>All consumers deliver messages in a serial order.
  * Acknowledging a received message automatically acknowledges all 
  * messages that have been delivered to the client.
  *
  * <P>Restarting a session causes it to take the following actions:
  *
  * <UL>
  *   <LI>Stop message delivery
  *   <LI>Mark all messages that might have been delivered but not 
  *       acknowledged as "redelivered"
  *   <LI>Restart the delivery sequence including all unacknowledged 
  *       messages that had been previously delivered. Redelivered messages
  *       do not have to be delivered in 
  *       exactly their original delivery order.
  * </UL>
  *
  * @exception JMSException if the JMS provider fails to stop and restart
  *                         message delivery due to some internal error.
  * @exception IllegalStateException if the method is called by a 
  *                         transacted session.
  */ 

void
recover() throws JMSException;
```

For other readers - if you use AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE with a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` you must use transactions to roll back the ack.

Comment: I added more explanation as to why.

Comment: @Garry so what is the difference between auto acknowledge and client acknowledge? I got the same results with both of them. When exception is thrown in a consumer, both with a client acknowledgment and auto acknowledgment it gets redelivered. Also, without calling message.acknowledge() it's still acknowledged for both client and auto option.

Comment: See the javadocs for `Session`. Auto means the provider library automatically acks the message when `consumer.receive()` returns it, or the `consumer.messsageListener()` exits. With a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, your listener is called directly by the provider's `Consumer` so messages won't be auto-ack'd until your listener exits normally. The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` calls `receive()` instead and calls your listener on its own thread. Hence we need transactions to roll back the ack.

Comment: With client mode, records are not ack'd until your code does. They are removed from the queue. This becomes permanent if you ack the message (or a later one). They will be requeued only when the `Session` is either closed or `recover()`ed before acking them.

Comment: Important note— client ack mode acknowledges *all* outstanding messages on a session. If you add multi threading you can unintentionally ack or recover incorrectly. It is not a per-message ACK pattern. See: INDIVIDUAL_ACK for that pattern